# subclassed empty numpy recarray losing its type and added attributes in numpy 1.8

Tags: python, numpy, attributes, subclass, recarray

I am trying to implement a subclass of a numpy recarray (recsub) and assign instances of it to an ndarray of dtype 'object' (ndarr). It works well, but i have a problem when the subclassed recarray is instantiated with an empty array. This is the code for the subclassed recarry:

```
class recsub(numpy.recarray):
"""subclassed recarray"""

def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):

    obj = numpy.recarray.__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)

    return obj

def __init__(self, *arg, **kwargs):

    self.x = -1

def new_method(self):
    print 'new_method() : fooooooooooooo'
```

I create the ndarray as :

```
ndarr = numpy.ndarray(5, 'object')
```

now if i create two instances of recsub :

```
ndarr[0] = recsub(2, [('a','f8')])
ndarr[1] = recsub((), [('a','f8')])
```

Now here is the weird stuff that is happening. The output of :

```
print type(ndarr[0])
print type(ndarr[1])
```

is:

```
>>> <class '__main__.recsub'>
>>> <class 'numpy.core.records.record'>
```

so i can not access ndarr[1].x

This used to work in numpy 1.7, but not anymore in numpy 1.8! So it seems something is missing upon instantiating the recarray with a shape () as opposed to (n)

any suggestion is welcome,

tnx in advance,

Comment: `()` shaped, scalar arrays can behave rather differently, but I suggest you fix your code, `numpy.ndarray(5)` and assigning to that? That *can't* be right.

Comment: oh, sorry, that was meant to be 'ndarr = numpy.ndarray(5, 'object') i just copied it wrong. i'll fix it.

Comment: Hmm, it kinda looks like the item getting calls one layer of scalar conversion code too much for object arrays, but I didn't manage to pinpoint the change responsible. This should be a numpy issue not a SO question IMO...

Comment: Ah, I found the bug, but I don't like fixing issues based on SO questions :P

Answer (score 1):

I get similar behavior in dev 1.9 with simpler arrays

```
ndarr = np.ndarray(2,dtype=np.object)
x = np.array([1,2])
ndarr[0] = x
y = np.array(3)
ndarr[1] = y
type(ndarr[0])
# numpy.ndarray
type(ndarr[1])
# numpy.int32
ndarr
# array([array([1, 2]), 3], dtype=object)
```

So the array with shape `()` gets inserted into `ndarr` as a scalar.

I don't know whether this is a bug, feature, or intended consequence of some change between 1.7 and 1.8.  I guess the first place to look is the release notes for 1.8.

This issue may relevant: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/1679

```
array([array([]), array(0, object)])
array([array([], dtype=float64), 0], dtype=object)
```

with the bug fix, https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/4109, the items that were stored as `array` are returned in the same way (instead of as scalars).

```
type(ndarr[1])
# <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
ndarr
# [array([1, 2]) array(3)]
# [array([], dtype=float64) array(0, dtype=object)]
# [array([], dtype=float64) 0]
```

And the OP example runs as expected.

Comment: Don't let yourself be fooled by the printing, to inspect this here, try the `.item()` method instead. It actually gets inserted just fine ;), not that it matters...

Comment: it looks like a bug to me. Because this kind of behavior defeats the purpose of having an object dtype.

Comment: So the `numpy` but is in fetching (`ndarr[1]` for print or use), not in the storing.